# Proving that $V^{\otimes d} = U(\mathfrak g)v_0$

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

> Let $d\leq n, V=\mathbb C^{n+1}$ with basis $\{v_1,\cdots,v_{n+1}\}$, $ \mathfrak g = \mathfrak{sl}_{n+1}$ and $v_0 = v_{i_1}\otimes \cdots \otimes v_{i_d}\in V^{\otimes d}$ such that $i_1,\cdots, i_d \in \{1,\cdots,n+1\}$ are all distinct. How do I prove that $U(\mathfrak g)v_0 = V^{\otimes d}$ ?

**Some notation**: denote by $x_i^\pm$ the standard generators of $\mathfrak g$ such that $[x_i^+,x_i^-] =h_i$ and by $x_\theta^\pm$ the root vectors associated with the longest root $\theta$.
Regarding the action of $\mathfrak g$ on $V$, recall that  $x_i^-v_j = \delta_{i,j}v_{j+1},
x_i^+v_j = \delta_{i,j-1}v_{j-1}$ and that $x_\theta^-v_j=\delta_{1,j}v_{n+1},x_\theta^+v_j= \delta_{n+1,j}v_1.$ Also, $\mathfrak g$ acts on $V^{\otimes d}$ by $x(v_1\otimes \cdots \otimes v_d) = \sum_k v_1\otimes \cdots \otimes x.v_k\otimes \cdots \otimes v_d$.

**Toughts so far**: It suffices to show that all vectors of the form $v_{j_1}\otimes \cdots \otimes v_{j_d} \in U(\mathfrak g)v_0.$ I tried to use induction over $d$. It is valid for $d=1$, since $v_0 = v_i \in V$ and $v_j = x_{j-1}^- \cdots x_i^-v_0$ (supposing that $i<j$).

Since $x(v_{i_1}\otimes \cdots \otimes v_{i_d}) = (x(v_{i_1}\otimes \cdots \otimes v_{i_{d-1}})\otimes v_{i_d} + v_{i_1}\otimes \cdots \otimes v_{i_{d-1}}\otimes x .v_{i_d}$, using the induction hyphotesis, there exists a $x\in U(\mathfrak g)$ such that

$$ x(v_{i_1}\otimes \cdots \otimes v_{i_d})  = v_{j_1}\otimes \cdots \otimes v_{j_{d-1}}\otimes v_{i_d}+v_{i_1}\otimes \cdots \otimes v_{i_{d-1}}\otimes x.v_{i_d}.$$

Here comes the problem. Altough there exists $x' \in U(\mathfrak g)$ such that $x'.v_{i_d} = v_{j_d},$ it might be the case that some ${j_k} = i_d, 1\leq k \leq d-1,$ so applying $x'$ to both sides of the above equality will make the right hand side a sum of $v_{j_1}\otimes \cdots \otimes v_{j_d}$ with some other summands. If I could show that those other summands lie in the set $U(\mathfrak g)v_0$, its done. But that does not seem easy to argue.

Any insight on how to prove this? Thanks.

Comment: Aren't the rules like
$$x(v_{j_1}\otimes v_{j_2}\otimes v_{j_3})=(xv_{j_1})\otimes v_{j_2}\otimes v_{j_3}+
v_{j_1}\otimes (xv_{j_2})\otimes v_{j_3}+v_{j_1}\otimes v_{j_2}\otimes (xv_{j_3})$$ only valid when $x\in\mathfrak{g}$? As opposed to all the elements of the universal enveloping algebra.

Comment: Anyway, while the subscripts are distinct, the action of a root operator is easy to describe, meaning that we can easily move the indices around while their order does not change. The catch is to check what happens after some indices become equal after a sequence of root operators have been applied. I don't recall seeing this exercise before, but looks like it will be fun. Too bad I don't have time for this now.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen yeah, I tought that I could do it only using the root operators $x_i^\pm$, moving indexes "up" and "down" while avoiding indexes "crossing" each other out, to finally reach the goal vector. For $n+1=7,d = 3$, from $v_0 = v_1\otimes v_4\otimes v_7$ I can reach $v_3\otimes v_5 \otimes v_2$ through the string $x_1^-x_\theta^+x_4^-x_2^-x_1^-  $. While from $v_0 = v_1\otimes v_3 \otimes v_6$ I can never reach $v_4\otimes v_7 \otimes v_5$ using a string as simple as that one, because at some point the indexes must cross each other and thus messing up the sum by adding one more term.

Comment: If I draw a circle and choose $7$ points in it enumerated by $1,\cdots, 7$ with $1$ being the same point as $7$, I can visualize the vector $v_0 = v_1\otimes v_3 \otimes v_6$ in this circle by puting a marble of diferent color (red,yellow,green) over the points $1,3$ and $6$ respectively. The action of the operators $x_i^\pm, x_\theta^\pm$ on the vector $v_0$ is visualized by moving those marbles up and down throughout this circle. In the vector $v_4\otimes v_7 \otimes v_5$ the green marble is in the left side of the yellow one, while originally it was in the right. So those marbles must cross

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment but here's a start:

Since $v_1, v_2, \dots, v_{n+1}$ are linearly independent we can always find $x \in \mathfrak{sl}_{n+1}$ such that $x(v_j) = 0$ for $j \ne k$ and $x(v_k) = \sum_{\ell \ne k} a_\ell v_\ell$ for any constants $a_\ell$ we want (the trace zero condition is why there is no $a_k$ term). If you apply this to a vector $v_{i_1} \otimes \dots \otimes v_{i_d}$, if there is a term $v_{i_m} = v_k$ it will change it to $\sum_{\ell \ne k} a_\ell v_\ell$ but leave the rest of the terms the same.  Therefore applying the operator $a_\ell\cdot1 + x \in U(\mathfrak{g})$ we can change the term $v_k$ in the tensor to any other vector $v \in \mathbb{C}^{n+1}$ without changing the other tensor terms.

The idea is to then iterate this sort of construction to turn the starting vector into any other pure tensor $w_1 \otimes \dots \otimes w_d$ changing one term at a time.  I think a little care needs to be taken for when $w_1, \dots, w_d$ span a lower dimensional subspace, but that shouldn't be too hard (or maybe induction can handle that).